# Android studio вывод данных из manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Как можно вывести VersionName из manifest в TextView?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать такой способ:

```
try {
    PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = pInfo.versionName;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

версия кода:

```
int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-can-you-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application) можно найти больше инфы

Comment: Это куда впиндюрить нужно? Немного не понимаю

Comment: там где у вас текстовое поле, в активности или в фрагменте

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.